# Is it valid to have an inline element without a block-level parent?

Tags: html, css

I want to know if block-level, parent elements are technically-required for inline elements in an HTML document.  For example, the following `HTML`...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Some Text</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this a valid HTML document?  Or must the `<b>` and `</b>` tags be encapsulated in a block-level element to be considered valid, like `<p>` or `<div>`?  (Hopefully the answer is the same for HTML4 and HTML5?)

Many people ask a similar question: *Can I place a block-level element inside an inline element?* I want to know the opposite: *Can inline elements go anywhere besides in a block-level element in an HTML document?*

I am seeing this in an RFC:

> Certain HTML elements that may appear in BODY are said to be "block-level" while others are "inline" (also known as "text level")....
>
> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

But, it doesn't totally come out and say it.

Comment: you can valide your html and see

Comment: The most obvious example in HTML 4.01 of where an inline element can go as the child of a element that is neither block-level nor inline-level, is as the child of a table cell.

Comment: @Alohci : The `table` element is block-level, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements .  That would be "some parent", maybe not immediate, but distant, great-great grandparent possibly, but still a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a inline element anywhere, inside a block level, outside, wherever, even outside of the `body` if you wanted to! They'll render just the same, only without any padding/margin that you would expect of block level elements.

In the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) for inline elements, they are always - in the two examples give - shown inside of block-level elements, but that doesn't mean that they can't stand alone, outside of a block element. It just means that it generally isn't done because it is sematically wrong - ie, you have block level elements that contain inline elements, not lone-standing inline elements.

Although technically, the example you provided is not an example of an inline element outside a block element because the `body` is a block element.